# jQuery Mobile grid layout

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using grid layout in jQuery Mobile.  But when I add a div with the ui-bar class to each cell my buttons are not filling the whole cell.  Is there any way to make the buttons to fill the width of the cell?  Thanks.

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 60px; border-right-width: 0px;">User A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <div class="ui-bar ui-bar-d" style="height: 60px; border-left-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px;">
            <button data-icon='delete' data-theme='e'>Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have posted the html which jquery mobile should have rendered. I am not sure if this is what you wrote. However, if you have jquery mobile setup correctly, you should be able to do something like:

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <button type="submit" data-theme="c" name='user'>
            User A
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">
        <button type="submit" data-theme="b" name='delete'>
            Delete
        </button>
    </div>     
</fieldset>
```